# Difference between Golang struct literals & pointers when accessing struct fields

Tags: pointers, struct, go

I don't understand the difference between a struct literal and a struct pointer **when accessing struct fields**. Is there any different internal behavior ?

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
}

p := &Person{Name: "Alice"}
u := Person{Name: "Bob"}

fmt.Println(p.Name)  // any difference ?
fmt.Println(u.Name)  // any difference ?
```

I searched for this but posts I found all explain about difference between value & pointer, or "passing a value" vs "passing a pointer" to a method. They are not what I want to know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`u` is a variable of type `Person`. `p` is a variable of type "pointer to `Person`", and it is initialized with the address of an anonymous ("temporary") object. The expression `p.Name` uses auto-dereferencing of pointers and is equivalent to `(*p).Name`. The object that `p` points to lives as long as `p` points to it and may thereafter be destroyed by Go's non-deterministic memory manager.

Both `p.Name` and `u.Name` are expressions of type `string`, and they're not "passed by pointer" since their address is not taken in the call. In the case of `fmt.Println`, the value is actually passed "by interface" using Go's structural subtyping form of ad-hoc polymorphism.

Comment: Yes! "auto-dereferencing of pointers" is exactly the keyword that I wanted to search for but did not know.

Your answer is very helpful and clear. 

Thank you.

Comment: For someone who is less familiar with Go, and pointers/refs in general, can this be explained in layman's terms? What are the practical implications?